# Return time.now with millisecond precision

Tags: c#, time

I'm currently programming a simulator with sensors that return a value at a very high speed. Because of the abundance of logging that's going on, it's very important to me to get the lineup correct. In order to do this I'm trying to get the timer to line up as well. This however forms an issue. When returning the milliseconds it often returns .01 .1 or even no milliseconds. This is slighty throwing off the lineup. Any idea how to force it to return for example .000?

Basicly i'm trying to make this:

```
[DEBUG]|18:48:39.449| Sonar 10d | Sonar1 40d | 7.684386
[DEBUG]|18:48:39.45| Sonar 10d | Sonar1 10d | 27.54916
[DEBUG]|18:48:39.5| Sonar 10d | Sonar1 20d | 14.52461
[DEBUG]|18:48:39| Sonar 10d | Sonar1 30d | 9.878839
```

Look more like this:

```
[DEBUG]|18:48:39.449| Sonar 10d | Sonar1 40d | 7.684386
[DEBUG]|18:48:39.450| Sonar 10d | Sonar1 10d | 27.54916
[DEBUG]|18:48:39.500| Sonar 10d | Sonar1 20d | 14.52461
[DEBUG]|18:48:39.000| Sonar 10d | Sonar1 30d | 9.878839
```

Without using too much code like I'm doing at the moment.

Current code:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;    
time.ToString("HH:mm:ss.FFF");
```

And then too much code to add the . and 0's ...

Comment: One line is considered "too much code"?  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: You know `18:48:39.45` means the same thing as `18:48:39.450`, right?

Comment: In case it is relevant for other fields you may be interested in String.PadRight (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright(v=vs.110).aspx). This will pad a string to a given length. Useful if for example you end up with a Sonar10 or something like that.

Comment: @Plutonix, that wasn't what I was asking for though. As I explained I wanted the data to line-up better. This would require 18:48:39 to be the same length as 18:48:39.283. Which makes the accepted solution perfect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `fff` instead of `FFF`

```
time.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Example

```
var now = new DateTime(2017,10,18,12,16,16, 10);
Console.WriteLine("What you want {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}", now);
Console.WriteLine("WHat you have {0:HH:mm:ss.FFF}", now);
```

Produces output

```
What you want 12:16:16.010
WHat you have 12:16:16.01
```

For more format string options see [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: Perfect. That was what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can try a line like below (note the lower case `f`)

```
time.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

You can test it with the below code

```
var s = DateTime.ParseExact("20170810 18:20:13", "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss", null).ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

This should print the following output

```
18:20:13.000
```